# traversing a Backbone Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have just started integrating backbone.js in my application. I have a question about traversing each model in collection.

I basically want to get urls of each model in the collection and attach those urls to its corresponding model. I'm doing it this way right now, and I just want to know if there is any other way of doing it?

```
getItemsURLs: function(collection){

    var idsInCollection = [];

    collection.each(function(model) {
       idsInCollection.push(model.get('id'));
    });

    makeServiceCall({
        data: idsInCollection,
        success: function(data) {
            collection.each(function(model,i) {
                model.set({ url: data.urls[i]});
            });
        }
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `pluck` is more concise:

```
var idsInCollection = collection.pluck('id');
```

*(As pointed out by asawyer, `pluck` is more concise than `map` or `each`.)*

Comment: That is awesome. I knew I would get something out of this question.
What about setting an attribute, do we have method similar to pluck to set urls?

Comment: @johnknaan Not that I'm aware of. `pluck` actually comes from the underscore.js library.